# Calculating exact runtime, not actual runtime

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, timing

Is is possible to create a program that, say with byte code, runs your program as normal, keeping a tally of the total run-time by using defined run-times of each instruction as you go? Then, once your program finished, you'd have an exact, system independent value for the run-time, without the need of running your program over and over and averaging the results, or finding the min. Sure the relation between this and actual run-time differs depending on excessive quantities of variables, but it still seems like such a figure would be nice to at least have the option to use.

So, for clarity, there's three questions here (sorry, but this just prevents follow up questions for conciseness), building on each other:

1. Is it possible, or is there a theoretical result that prevents this (halting problem or something)?
2. If it is possible, why is this never used? It seems valuable for many practical reasons.
3. Or is there one that exists and I am just missing it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask  This question is too open-ended.

Comment: What you suggest is probably impractical.  The number of variables that affect execution time of a piece of code on modern systems is legion.  Even air temperature and humidity can affect execution time.

Comment: Your best bet is probably a virtual machine which has a counter. This is an... unusual level of optimisation, though. Often you can theorise about the code at this level.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Why? I just asked if a simple program that could predict program run-time exists, or if not, if it could exist, or why it doesn't. There's no opportunity for opinion or interpretation, really.

Comment: "if it could exist" is always open ended.

Comment: @Taylor That's true, but the point of this wasn't really to predict run-time per say, but instead, to give an exact measure of time that is comparable between programs. Essentially, timing tests are inaccurate because of those small factors, but the algorithms are constant, so why don't we focus on that in comparing performance instead?

Comment: @Taylor True, but that was more meant to be a clarification. Essentially, 3 options: Either it's theoretically not possible, it's possible but nobody made it yet (why?), or it's possible, exists, and I just haven't seen it yet. I was just trying to cover all my bases, to prevent asking a follow up question.

Comment: @Dave Often yes, you're right, and that's a better way of doing it, but sometimes it's nice to get a visual approximation first, or to just use timing to verify what you predicted. This method would be exact, thus more fitting for these purposes.

Comment: *"I understand that this isn't always possible via the Halting Problem"* This is the whole answer.

Comment: @dmckee I'd believe maybe there's some deeper meaning in the Halting Problem that I don't understand that prevents what I'm suggesting, but, as far as I understand, I'm saying _if you know it will halt_, is this possible (just running the program and keeping a tally as you go)? Could you expound upon what you mean a little?

Comment: Isn't what you described basically the JVM (i.e. not simple), except keeping a count of instructions interpreted? And of course fairly slow since you can't use JIT or optimisations. I'm guessing the reason nobody made such a thing is because it doesn't sound at all practical - the only use case you've outlined is "making a smooth graph", except it'd be a graph of a numbers (a bunch of opcode counters) multiplied by more meaningless numbers (the estimated execution time of an opcode, which doesn't sound like it's a meaningful measure at all - it says nothing about the execution time after JIT.)

Comment: @Xilo27 you mean big O notation?

Comment: @Taylor Yea basically that was what I was talking about - except then you could has a visual representation of it with the constants as well. But millimoose you're probably right - after looking at the docs of JVM, it's complex to say the least, and all the JIT optimizations make it pointless anyway - especially because of the problems described in the answer below.

Comment: Why is this closed? The question seemed pretty clear I thought (is it possible to make a thing like millimoose described up above), and they gave a great answer (yes, but there's no real value to it because it'd be very hard to do, and the "accuracy" would still be not helpful as usually for timing you need to find the average results on a large variety of inputs) - what's problematic here? Sorry about this too - I'm just new to Stack Overflow and trying to learn how to be a good stack overflowing citizen - but I think I need some help as it looks like my questions aren't going so well so far.

Comment: (And sorry - I will keep answers I get later on out of the question from now on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic problem is that the number of times each instruction or method or whatever is executed is NOT a reliable predictor of anything ... except how long it will take to run the same program on the same input again.

To get a useful predictor, you need a good model of how the program's execution time depends on its inputs.  Producing such a model automatically is not a tractable problem.

- The Halting Theorem says that you cannot determine *a priori* whether any program is going to halt with a given input set.
- In practice, theorem proving technology is not up to the task for anything but really simple programs.
- Attempting to get model by empirical means (i.e. by trying to fit a curve to experimental results) is not going to work because:

  - It is not possible to work out (automatically) what the key variables are for the model.  Indeed, the variables may not even be numeric.
  - Even if you managed that, you've now way of knowing if the program's performance is going to fit one of the classic curves with any degree of accuracy.  You may get a model, but you have know way of knowing how accurate it will be.

---

Just to illustrate, consider the problem of factoring a large number.  If the number has small factors, then the computation time will be quick.  If it doesn't then ... well according to wikipedia, the worst case computational complexity of the best available method for factoring integers is:

```
O(exp(((64b/9)^(1/2).(log b)^(2/3)))
```

where `b` is the number of bits in the number.  That's intractable for large values of `b`.

So ...

- A analytical solution which could give us a useful prediction would be equivalent to finding a fast analytical solution that says whether a number is (definitely) factorizable, and how large the factors are.  This is a mathematically challenging problem.
- An empirical solution cannot exist because no useful empirical model  exists ... that doesn't involve first doing the factorization.

Comment: True, the only time timing code is really valuable is when you test it on lots of random input, and in that case this method is just as inexact as regular timing, so it doesn't have much of a benefit. That's a bummer, but makes sense, thanks!

Comment: I understood the other part you added already, it wasn't what I was asking - but thanks anyway, that covers all the alternative options (that aren't feasible) well.

Answer (score 0):

Java implementation:

```
int start = System.currentTimeMillis();

//Code to be timed...

int end = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println(end - start);
```

Comment: Yes of course, but that's not was I was saying. That method is inaccurate - to get a number close to the exact time of your code you have to run it over and over, then average the results (which is a pain). Instead, since we really don't care how long it takes, just relative times, could we abstract things away and compute what I was describing above instead?

Comment: To be fair, of course, sometimes the times matter. But other times, we are just comparing one algorithm to the other, and, in that case, relative, exact results are much more helpful and reliable.

Comment: @Xilo27 to get close to what you're looking for, don't average, take the minimum. The "true" run time will always be less than any time you observe. If your script is small enough, the true runtime may even *be* the shortest time you observe (if you got super lucky with system calls). For the real world, yes, average it.

Comment: @Dave Good point - thanks. Still though, even that is inaccurate, to find a good minimum you have to run it over and over just like the averaging. Instead, I guess moreso I'm asking, why wouldn't a program like the one I suggested above be useful for evaluating/comparing algorithms? If you ran it on the byte code it'd  be system independent too - wouldn't something like that be useful for algorithm analysis?

Comment: @Xilo27 no, because once you reach the point where you care about such small differences, you're already in the final (super-final) stages of optimisation, and will be optimising for a particular run-time environment. There's no point optimising it perfectly for a non-existent machine. For basic analysis of methods, O-notation and less accurate benchmarks (often with exaggerated inputs) are perfectly sufficient.

Comment: @Dave That somewhat makes sense, but still, if anything it seems like this would simply provide an easier means of providing timing code (and not be that hard to do). The exactness isn't only for optimization (and you're right, probably wouldn't be that helpful for that) but, if anything just so you can have smooth graphs for displaying data. This is pretty important for, if anything, just showing the complexity of an algorithm more accurately. There's no reason to clutter the graphs with timing inaccuracies, and obtaining an exact result would be faster to find anyway, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

If you run all programs in the same machine and use time of the Proccess not the real run time the results should be very accurrate. Take a look to the class Proccess in .Net framework for an ease understanding of this (it contains properties that give you the UserTime and the KernelTime of the proccess itself) also this class is a good wraper to the OS proccess API.
Another look for analising the algorithm execution or completixity is given by the O notation that would require a deep analisis of the code, the problem with that is each operation dont take the same time, all this theory is maded for an ideal machine.
Maibe for do something like that you will need interpreters for all the languages that you want to support and make all that will be extreme complex.

Comment: Nice, thanks, this is a start, but still the problem here would be that with most computers, the operating system causes you to run more than one program at once on your processor (mouse desktop, etc. as well as program). These inevitably lead to timing inaccuracies, many of which are outside your control. This, plus things like automatic garbage collection which has nothing to do with the run-time of the algorithm itself lead to more inaccuracies that prevent accurate comparison.

Comment: Check the Proccess class (the 2 properties i mentioned before) it will give to you the real process time not the time that you percieve as person, it will give you the time the proccesor spend in it.

Comment: Ah I see, sorry, I misunderstood you, the Proccess is your specific program that's running, not the processor itself. In that case, this seems amazing - why don't we usually use this instead of millis and such for timing code? And do you know if there's a java equivalent? (the Java Process class didn't seem to have similar functions)

Comment: I know equivalen class to do it in c++ actually there are API for the operating system that give you all that information about a procces: GetProcessTimes(pinfo.hProcess, (_FILETIME *)&CreationTime,(_FILETIME *)&ExitTime, (_FILETIME *)&KernelTime,(_FILETIME *)&UserTime); but i am not a java programmer.

Comment: That's fine, do you know why we don't normally use these functions for timing code instead of the less accurate other ones though? I can see the value in both, but there are many cases in which it seems like this more accurate result would be better - yet we never even discuss it.

Comment: I have familiar with that because once a work in and Online Judge for my university (similar to SPOJ) in that site we must mesure the very accurate time, memory and result for solutions (algorithm) for matematical problems. regards.

Comment: I see, thanks - I guess it just wasn't needed to be that detailed in my programming classes so far. This still doesn't quite answer my question though: Would it possible to make a *system independent*, *exact* measure for the approximate time that programs take, generated simply by running the programs? That seems much more valuable.

Comment: for that two options: - make an interpreter that run this language under your control and other aproach but not so presice will give maybe to divide the Procces Times (that i mentioned before) by the speed of the proccesor or something like that.

Comment: The speed option would work - but yea that seems like it kinda defeats the purpose, it's still pretty inaccurate. I put this question I'm asking in this comment up at the top so we wouldn't need to be spamming the chat too, but just to have it here for completion, wouldn't the increased accuracy of the first method be better for displaying complexity in less time than any current option? It looks like Java doesn't have a process too, most importantly. If something's so simple and would be so nice, why doesn't it exist?